# Sticky navigation bar in header

Tags: html, css, menu, header, navigation

Hi I am trying to make my navigation menu stay on top of my page.

The search bar the help are on top but I want main to be the navigation and on the place where is **StackExchange** but more in left to be my logo.

And when I scroll down, the `nav menu-header` to stack on top and content go behind it .

I have no code because I pissed of and I don't know from where to start I've tried to make all in one div, but nothing happened....after this I tried to fix them (I've made them one under another) this way but only nav menu fixed and header disappeared but when I fix header...it's impposible to scroll down....I will really appriciate if someone can give me HTML and CSS example ....because I have no idea how I can do that

Comment: use the internet luke!

Comment: "I have no code because I pissed of and I don't know from where to start I've tried to make all in one div, but nothing happened" --- this is like telling your auto mechanic friend that you don't have a car to show him, but you know it's broken down, could he fix it even though it's in a ditch three counties away.

Answer (score 7):

Set up your header to have it css property like this:

**BASIC HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head><title>Sticky header</title><head>
    <body>
        <div id="header>Your nav goes here</div>
        <div id="content">Content things go here.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 500;
    height: 45px;
}

#content {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

with this you will be sure that your header will be always visible no matter if the user will scroll down, and the z-index is to make sure that the header will be always on top of the other content, if you have modals, give the modals z-index: 1000; so that you make sure that the modals will not be cut of by your header.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is part of a solution, though there's no way of really telling if the OP has arranged his markup so that this would work. You'd also need to set some top padding or margins to make sure that content that is under neath would not be hidden, as `position: fixed` removes the #header div from the document flow.

Comment: It is just an example in order to apply it to his markup. Nevertheless, I just eddited with a basic html example.

Comment: Sure, wasn't so much a criticism (as at least you provided some code and explanation!) as much as a refinement.

Comment: well, the request he made was quite clear, he could provide some of his code though, but i think that with the basic html example, he could then apply it to his (or any) markup.

Comment: Thank you i think that may work i will try it now ))

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.navbar {
 position: fixed;
 top:0;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1030;
}
```